# How to show data order by created_at in index.html.erb in rails instead of updated_at ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am little embarrassed that I am not able to figure out this but index.html.erb is showing some data order by updated_at where as I want to order it by created_at with latest one at the top. How can I do this ?

my index.html.erb is the standard one

```
<% @products do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you defined @products, you could also use order, as in:

```
Product.order('created_at DESC')
```

That would show all products and be sorted by created_at in descending order.

But if you use Product.all.order('created_at DESC'), for example, it will not work because .all turns the results into an array.  In that case, you would need to use sort_by, as the other answer suggested.

Order will work in your model, as long as you are not using it on an array.

Comment: If possible this is preferable to using Ruby to sort the Array of records returned (**much** more efficient).

Comment: I have @ products = current_user.products so I guess @ products = current_user.products.order('created_at DESC') should work, right ?

Comment: Yes, ActiveRecord will combine the scope and the ordering correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your controller

`@products = @products.sort_by {|obj| obj.created_at }.reverse`

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: can I do this at model level too ? does it make any difference ?

Comment: Would perhaps have to be `@products.all.sort_by`... since .all will allow you to call the Enumerable function #sort_by. However I'd still recommend doing this via the DB as this is what databases were made for.

Comment: I totally agree with @AaronCronin